# coker of a polynomial matrix whose entries are permutations of the indeterminates

Tags: matrices, commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[x,y,z]$ and $m=(x,y,z)$. Consider the matrix $\phi=\begin{bmatrix} x & y & z\\ y & z & x \\ z & x & y\end{bmatrix}$ and the complex $R^3\xrightarrow{\phi} R^3$. Is it true that image of $\phi$ is $m\oplus m\oplus m$, and $\operatorname{coker}\phi=(R/m)^3$  ?

If not, what is the $\operatorname{coker}\phi=R^3/\operatorname{im}\phi$ isomorphic to?

Is there a special name for these types of matrices?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: THanks for the reply. But after posting, i worked on it a bit more and thought that this was not true. For example, (x,0,0) is in $m\oplus m\oplus m$,but Cramer's rule will say that (x,0,0) is not in the image of $\phi$. So could you explain a bit more as to why it is true?

Comment: All I can say is that the coker of $\phi$ is a torsion $R$-module: $(\det\phi)$(coker)=0